# Pythonic way to set variable from another sublist match

Tags: python, list, variables

I wasn't even sure how to title my post -- if I did I might have found what I was looking for. :) I'm trying set a variable from another list. Let's say my current value in my loop has the model variable set like this:

`model = "hybrid"`

And I want to join to another list and pull a value. The other list looks like this:

`ratings = [['hybrid',400],['gas',600],['electric',200]]`

How can I set the variable "power" to 400 in a single statement?

This obviously doesn't work, but it might show you what I'm trying to do:

`power = x[1] for x in ratings if x[0] == model`

Answer (score 2):

Add brackets to it to become a list comprehension:

```
power = [x[1] for x in ratings if x[0] == model]
```

If you don't want it as a list, you want it as a singular instead, use:

```
power = next((x[1] for x in ratings if x[0] == model), None)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I like how it gives me the option for a default value if no match found. Thanks for the super quick response!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dict(ratings)[model]
400
```

Plus that's a hint for how you might want to store your ratings instead.